# link_to and the destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, link-to

I have an app where you add games (found via API) to a user's library, but I also want the user to delete games from a library. However I am not sure if I am using the correct link_to path or if the issue is with my controller.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'library_game/index'
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  get '/games', to: 'games#index', as: :index
  get '/user/:id', to: 'user#show'
  resource :user, only: [] do
  resources :games, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
  get '/user/:id/library', to: 'library#index', as: :library
  post '/user/:id/library', to: 'games#create', as: :create
  delete 'user/:id/library', to: 'games#destroy', as: :destroy
end
```

My game model

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :library_games
  has_many :libraries, through: :library_games
  has_many :users, through: :libraries
  serialize :data
  attr_accessor :game_id

  def fetch_data
    game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(game_id)
    self.data = Hash[game.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], game.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]
  end

  def to_giant_bomb_game
    GiantBomb::Game.new(data)
  end
end
```

My link_to for deleting:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove from library', destroy_path(current_user, game_id: game.id), method: :delete %>
```

My controller method for destroy:

```
def destroy
    current_user.games.where(game_id: params[:id]).destroy_all
    redirect_to library_path
  end
```

With what I have now, I am getting this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in GamesController#destroy
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column games.game_id does not exist

So the error throws up an issue with the controller, but I am wondering if the real culprit is that my link_to is not passing the correct data. What should I be passing to my link_to?

Comment: @SJKDo you want delete game or data from users game library?

Comment: Change `game_id` param to `id` param. `destroy_path(current_user, id: game.id)`. Because here in controller you're using `id`: `current_user.games.where(game_id: params[:id]).destroy_all`

Comment: @NatarajaB I want to delete the data from the user's game library. The game should still be searchable.

Comment: @snake I tried your method, but it changes the link_to URL from ~/user/1/library?game_id=68737 to ~/user/68737/library.1 and throws up a Statement Invalid, undefined column error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is `LibraryGame` (as in it has a `library_id` and a `game_id`) then this

```
resource :user, only: [] do
  resources :games, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

needs to be

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :library_games, only: [:create, :destroy], shallow: true
end
```

The `shallow: true`, gives you routes like `users/1/library_games/x` for index, create, and new, but routes like `library_games/x` for show, edit, update, and destroy. Best of both worlds.

And then your link would be `<%= link_to "Remove from Library", library_game_path(library_game), method: :delete %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your html (with the inspector tool in the browser) what link the link_to helper method is generating.
You have 2 routes in routes.rb that deal with the deletion of games, but since your using `destroy_path` this is the one that's interesting:

```
 delete 'user/:id/library', to: 'games#destroy', as: :destroy
```

See how there is one placeholder for `:id`? This is the user id, not the game id, however in the destroy action in your controller you look for the game with `params[:id]` which is the user id

```
...(game_id: params[:id])...
```

And this is why it fails.

You need to clean up your routes. In the one above, why is the path `user/:id/library` but it goes to the games controller. Why is there another route above that deals with the deletion of games? In ruby on rails everything is about conventions, and you should follow them too.
You also want to look into nested routing https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

For a destroy action you normally don't need to nest the route because with the id of the game you should be able to find it in the database and destroy it. Also you have devise so you can work with the `current_user` which you already do.
So you could just have the route like this:

```
resources :games, only: :destroy
```

and then use the link_to method

```
<%= link_to 'Remove from library', game_path(game.id), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: I see that I have a superfluous destroy method. However I am not destroying the game, just the association between the game and the user's library.

As it stands now my URL is going to  ~/user/1/library?game_id=68737. Using the link_to method gives me an error because I don't have a game_path. My delete method is tied to user_game_path, but even changing it links to ~/user/games/68737 and I get UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column games.game_id does not exist.

Comment: in the destroy method you posted, you're destroying the game: `games.where(game_id: params[:id]).destroy_all`. According to your game model `library_games` is the joint table between game and a user library, no?

Comment: Yes. In the create method the user puts a game into games, so I do want to destroy that game instance. Maybe I am wording it in a confusing manner. Here is my create method:
```
def create
    @library_game = Game.new
    @library_game.game_id = params[:game_id]
    @library_game.fetch_data
    @library_game.save!
    current_user.build_library
    current_user.library.games << @library_game
    redirect_to library_path
  end
```
I tried current_user.library.games.where(game_id: params[:id]).destroy_all but I get the same error as if I didn't include library.

Comment: I see that you have a nice answer already, but why do you save a new instance of `Game` in a variable `@library_game` per your create method but you also have a library_game model...